# Is this an exchange for novelists, poets, lyricists, and writers of all kinds?

Tags: discussion

I am new to Stack Exchange, and do not wish to step on any toes or offend anyone. I searched for a group specific to poetry and song-writing, as this is my forté. I am an aspiring novelist as well, so if this group best encapsulates writing of all formats I will be glad to be here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is for all types of writing.

But there are restrictions on questions. We don't do reviews or critiques of writing, for example, this is not the place to earn points for good writing. This is not a place to get "feedback" on your writing.

We do not give specific plot or story advice. A question like "what should my character do now?" is off limits.

And there is a separate Stack Exchange for "World Building", you should check that out to see the types of questions that get answered there. I keep a tab for each open on my browser. They do allow specific answers to some questions that would be regarded as story help; but it is focused on non-real-world cultures, alien races, etc.

Likewise, there is a separate Stack Exchange for English Language and Usage; if you have grammar questions.

We offer advice on writing that is not specific to any one particular piece of writing work.

Comment: Thank you so much for this brilliant answer. That is the information that I was seeking.  I would likely not be indulging Language and Usage and 'World Building' is not my downfall.  My challenge is cohesion, but those are questions for another day!

Comment: P.S. Upvoting is free, of both questions and answers; if you find other questions interesting or their answers on point. Even if you get more answers you like, upvote as many as you like. And if you want to change your accepted answer, you can.

Comment: I would love to, but I have not attained an appropriate level! smh

Comment: I love the name, by the way. I was once coined 'Mozart' while playing piano for a friend of mine. Now I have the tattoo to show for it! *SMH*

Comment: Most people don't know that Amadeus is not in Mozart's full name. He was named "Johannes Chrysostomus Wolfgangus Theophilus Mozart". His female cousin (and lover, as teens) translated "Theophilus" ("Lover of God") to Latin ("Amadeus"), which he liked. His letters to her were mostly affectionate (and sometimes racy), and he signed some of those with fake pomposity and curlicue flourishes, as "Wolfgangus Amadeus Mozartus".